# echo multiple lines with CMD to .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

I need to use CMD to echo these lines :

```
@ECHO OFF 

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Atelier Web\Remote Commander Pro\
awrcp.exe /r=test

goto end

:end
```

to .bat file

Answer (score 0):

Well remove `echo off`. Really.